# Android widget Image preview is not changing even after deleting the by default image in AS

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

Here is the `widget_info.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/new_app_widget"
android:initialLayout="@layout/new_app_widget"
android:minHeight="40dp"
android:minWidth="180dp"
android:previewImage="@drawable/example_appwidget_preview"
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
android:widgetCategory="home_screen"/>
```

This is by default when we create the widget, but the problem is whatever  i do either the delete the previewImage mentioned in the code or modify it, it will still show the same default image but it won't change to the drawable that i have provided. why???

Answer (score 1):

This is a known [Android issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81076). There is currently no official response from the Google or Android team, but it might be useful to Star that issue to be notified of future changes.

The main workaround is for the user to restart device or do this:

```
Settings -> Apps -> Google App -> Manage Space -> Clear Launcher Data
```

Seems to be an issue in Lollipop 5.0 and 5.1.1

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10761725)

Comment: @mbaitoff Point taken, but it serves little purpose to delete useful information, even it if does not confirm to the perfect Answer.